# Python sqlite: using executemany() with unspecified number of parameters

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using python3 with pyodbc library.
I am fetching data from the remote MSSQL database into the local sqlite file. I have a table named 'Products' in both databases, i'm doing something like this:

```
prod_list = remote_db.cursor.execute('select * from Products').fetchall()
local_db.cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO Products VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)', prod_list)
```

Works well until i have a table with over 50 fields. Do i really have to write '?' fifty times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider dynamically creating the prepared statement conditioned on length of `prod_list`:

```py
qmarks = ", ".join('?' for i in prod_list[0])

sql = f"INSERT INTO Products VALUES ({qmarks})"
local_db.cursor.executemany(sql, prod_list)
```